# Average correlation of Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $(X_n)_n$ be a countable-state, positive recurrent, aperiodic Markov chain, so that stationary distribution $\pi$ exists. Let $S$ denote the state space. Consider bounded functions $f, g:S\to \mathbb{R}$. It follows from the total variation convergence that $E[f(X_n)] \to E_\pi[f(X_0)]$.

Question: Is it true that $ \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i,j=1}^n E[f(X_i) g(X_j)]\to E_\pi[f(X_0)]E_\pi[g(X_0)]$?

Attempt: If $i<j$, then \begin{align*}
E[f(X_i) g(X_j)] &= E\Big[E[f(X_i) g(X_j)|X_i]\Big] \\
&= E\Big[f(X_i) E[g(X_j)|X_i]\Big] \\
&= E\Big[f(X_i) E_{X_i}[g(X_{j-i})]\Big] \\
\end{align*} by Markov property. Then if $j-i\to \infty$, by DCT (everything is bounded) we have
$$E[f(X_i) g(X_j)] \to E\Big[f(X_i) E_{\pi}[g(X_{0})]\Big]
=E[f(X_i)]E_{\pi}[g(X_{0})].$$
Now if $i\to\infty$, we would get $$E[f(X_i) g(X_j)] \to 
E_\pi[f(X_0)]E_{\pi}[g(X_{0})].$$

The idea is that, if $n$ is large, then all large $i, j$ terms would be close to $E_\pi[f(X_0)]E_{\pi}[g(X_{0})]$, and the finitely many small $i,j$ terms would not matter because of the $1/n^2$ decay. Is it possible to make this idea rigorous?

Also, is it possible to calculate how fast the average converge to the limit?

Thank you in advance